# Falling through to super.validateMenuItem(:) generates Swift exception

Tags: swift, macos, exception, super, nsmenuitem

I have a class, `MyViewController`, with several actions which are triggered from menu items.

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController { … }
```

The actions are connected to first responder in IB. Actions look like this:

```
@IBAction func removeSelectedItems(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    arrayController.remove(contentsOf: arrayController.selectedObjects)
}
```

`validateMenuItem(:)` code looks like this:

```
override func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
    let selection = arrayController.selectedObjects

    if (menuItem.action == #selector(removeSelectedItems(_:))) {
        return selection!.count > 0
    }

    return super.validateMenuItem(menuItem)
}
```

When I include the actions in the `if()` list, everything is fine. But if I don't, and `validateMenuItem(:)` falls through to super, I get an exception:

```
[MyApp.MyViewController validateMenuItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x618000165ac0
```

If I instead `return false` at the end of the method, there's no exception.

This happens when `validateMenuItem(:)` is called, e.g. when the menu is opened. In spite of this, though, the action is triggered when the item is selected.

Am I wrong to be calling `super` at the end of the method? I would expect the responder chain to be queried until a match was found, not an exception claiming I didn't implement a method which I clearly did!

Comment: I am just curious, will there be changes when you use `super.validateMenuItem(:)` at the start of the overridden function and end of the overridden function?

Comment: No, the underlying state won't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I wrong to be calling super at the end of the method

Yes. Neither NSViewController nor any of its superclasses implements `validateMenuItem`. Despite the `override` in Swift, it is not actually inherited. It is injected in Objective-C by an informal protocol (NSMenuValidation). [The Swift compiler doesn't understand that kind of trickery; hence the `override` despite the fact that we are not overriding anything.]

See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46772

Comment: But the _real_ problem is that you should not be using `validateMenuItem:` at all.

Comment: "I would expect the responder chain to be queried until a match was found" Then you need to read the menu validation docs again. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I've gotten it working with `validateUserInterfaceItem(:)` now—just had to implement the `NSUserInterfaceValidations` protocol. I see that the responder chain checking only happens to find the object which implements the action. Still, though, it's super confusing that the exception claims my class doesn't implement `validateMenuItem(:)`!

Comment: "Still, though, it's super confusing that the exception claims my class doesn't implement validateMenuItem(:)" That is not what it claims.  There is only one instance in the story: your MyViewController. That is the instance that is messaged by calling `super`. That is what `MyApp.MyViewController` says in the exception log. Okay, so then the runtime tries to handle that message. The instance's class implements `validateMenuItem`, yes. But its _superclass_ has (and inherits) no such implementation. That is what `super` is looking for.

Comment: I thought I read that if an `NSMenuItem`'s target is nil, it will follow the responder chain, finding the first class that responds to its action.